# Which is fast : Query Syntax vs. Loops

Tags: c#, performance, loops, code-readability, linq-query-syntax

The following code provides two approaches that generate pairs of integers whose sum is less than 100, and they're arranged in descending order based on their distance from (0,0).

```
    //approach 1
    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>  ProduceIndices3()
    {
        var storage = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                if (x + y < 100)
                    storage.Add(Tuple.Create(x, y));
            }
        }
        storage.Sort((p1,p2) =>
           (p2.Item1 * p2.Item1 + 
           p2.Item2 * p2.Item2).CompareTo(
           p1.Item1 * p1.Item1 +
           p1.Item2 * p1.Item2));
        return storage;
    }

    //approach 2
    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> QueryIndices3()
    {
        return from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
               from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
               where x + y < 100
               orderby (x * x + y * y) descending
               select Tuple.Create(x, y);
    }
```

This code is taken from the book **Effective C#** by Bill Wagner, Item 8. In the entire article, the author has focused more on the syntax, the compactness and the readability of the code, but paid very little attention to the performance, and almost didn't discuss it.

So I basically want to know, which approach is faster? And what is usually better at performance (in general) : Query Syntax or Manual Loops?

Please discuss them in detail, providing references if any. :-)

Comment: The query has to devolve into a loop at some point, so there must be some overhead, even if the difference is negligible.

Comment: just from curiosity, could you explain this ordering?:
 orderby (x * x + y * y) descending
i don't understand how it works

Comment: the second one will be a lot faster, since it doesn't do anything but building a query, after doing a ToList() you will ba able to compare ;)

Comment: Notter: it's the distance from 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Profiling is truth, but my gut feeling would be that the loops are probably faster.  The important thing is that 99 times out of 100 the performance difference just doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.  Use the more readable version and your future self will thank you when you need to maintain it later.

Comment: If I may add, in the second method, the compiler can understand better the purpose of the code, so it can optimize it more properly. Maybe right now, even with optimizations, the first method will run faster, however, in a not so distant future, we might get better performance from the first one.

Comment: Profiling may be a little overkill for a small learning project. It's really easy to increase the number from 100 to 1,000,000 and just measure the difference in time with a stopwatch.

Comment: @Phil - I would consider that profiling, even though you aren't using a fancy tool to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Running each function 1000 times:

for loop: 2623 ms
query: 2821 ms

looks logic since the second one is just syntaxic sugar for the first one. But i would use the second one for its readability.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you profiled this, did you actually enumerate the query from the second function (e.g. using .ToList() or something?)

Comment: did ToList, it took about 3ms without that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Though this doesn't strictly answer your question, performance-wise I would suggest merging that x+y logic into the iteration, thus:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 100 - x; y++)
        storage.Add(Tuple.Create(x, y));
```

Comment: clever, but it would "biase" the speed comparison with the other function (need to change: from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 100-x))

Comment: In all honesty, any half-decent optimizing compiler should make this change negligible.