# How to use C# delegate like functor in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

In C++, to sort a vector, a list or any collection, I would use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vt;
    vt.push_back( 3 );
    vt.push_back( 1 );
    vt.push_back( 2 );
    sort( vt.begin(), vt.end(), greater<int>() );
}
```

In C#, I found that `List<>` is equivalent to `std::vector<>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Professional_Csharp {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            List<int> intList = new List<int>();
            intList.Add( 3 );
            intList.Add( 2 );
            intList.Add( 1 );
            intList.Sort(); 
        }
    }
}
```

This worked fine, however if I want to customize the comparator, how could I implement that? Or if I want to sort just a specific range instead of the whole list? How could I do that?

**Update**

```
sort( vt.begin(), vt.begin() + 1 );
```

Is it possible in C#?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: I suggest you get rid of the C++ code in the question; the questions you asked at the end are specific enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout the .NET framework you will occasionaly find methods (like Sort) which have one or more overloads which accept additional types (either interfaces or delegates) to extend their behavior. Unlike C++, .NET does not have the same approach as the STL to composable algorithms.

In the case of `List.Sort` there are two overloads that you may find useful:

```
List.Sort( IComparer<T> comparer )    // and
List.Sort( Comparison<T> comparison ) // .NET 4.0 and up
```

The first overload accepts an instance of a type that implements [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) - an interface with a single method `Compare`. The second overload is only available if you're using .NET 4.0 or newer - it accepts a delegate (or lambda expression) which supplies the comparison semantics.

If you can, the second overload is much easier to use:

```
intList.Sort( (a,b) => YourCompare(a,b) /* your compare logic here */ );
```

To use the first overload, you must create a class or struct that implements `IComparer<T>`:

```
public sealed class YourComparer : IComparer<YourType>
{
    int Compare( YourType a, YourType b ) { ... }
}

intList.Sort( new YourComparer() );
```

If you don't want to alter the collection itself, but only sort it's items and operate on them as a new sequence you can use LINQ's [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) operator:

```
intList.OrderBy( x => ... ).ToArray() /* creates new sequence, won't alter intList */
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, if you want to sort just a specific range of a particular collection, you would have to use the `Sort( int, int, IComparer<T> )` overload.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a comparison as a parameter to the sort method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx.  I would supply an example, but the one in that MSDN article should suffice.

Comment: Thanks. And how could I sort a specific range of that list?

Comment: You should supply an example so that your answer will still be relevant when MSDN changes their URLs.

Comment: Chan: `intList.Sort(0, intList.Count, comparer);`

Comment: @Chan: List<T>.Sort Method (Int32, Int32, IComparer<T>) sorts a range in the list.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad.aspx

Answer (score 2):

List.Sort() has overloads which accept lambdas to perform comparisons. For instance:

```
public class ElementClass {public int A; public int B;}

...

List<ElementClass> myList = GetAListOfRandomElementClassInstances();

//sorts in ascending order by A, then B
myList.Sort((x,y)=> x.A > y.A 
                    ? 1 
                    : x.A < y.A 
                      ? -1 
                      : x.B > y.B 
                        ? 1 
                        : x.B < y.B 
                          ? -1 
                          : 0);
```

List.Sort() will also take an IComparer, allowing you to encapsulate custom sorting behavior:

```
public class ElementClassComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int a, int b)
    {
        return x.A > y.A ? 1 : x.A < y.A ? -1 : x.B > y.B ? 1 : x.B < y.B ? -1 : 0
    }
}

...

myList.Sort(new ElementClassComparer());
```

The Linq library also has an OrderBy() method that will sort by any IComparable projection:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(x=>x.A).ThenBy(x=>x.B).ToList();
```

This is a less efficient but much more readable version of the above sorts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)` and write your custom IComparer.   [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, **List.Sort** has a few useful overloads. Here are just some implementation examples.

**IComparer<T>**

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<int> {
    public int Compare(int x, int y) {
        return x - y;
    }
}

...

List<int> list = new List<int>();

// Example start/end indexes
int startIndex = 0, endIndex = list.Count;

// Use IComparer<T>
MyComparer comparer = new MyComparer();
list.Sort(startIndex, endIndex, comparer);
```

**Comparison<T>**

```
static int MyCompareMethod(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}

...

// Use Comparison<T>
list.Sort((x, y) => MyCompareMethod(x, y));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although my post doesn't attempt to answer your question, as people already have given that. So I would talk about an alternative.

Suppose you want to sort `Person` by Age, then you can write query like code:

```
var sortedPersons = from person in persons
                    where true
                    orderby person.Age ascending
                    select person;
```

This syntax is very expressive and so appealing that recently I had started the following topic on it.

[Which is fast : Query Syntax vs. Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751527/which-is-fast-query-syntax-vs-loops)

Check it out. :-)